# 2D arrays in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

So I just started using Fortran, and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. I'm just trying to read values from a text file, put it into two integers, and create a 2D array.

```
program matrix
    IMPLICIT none
    integer :: a , b
    open (unit = 100, file = "test.txt")
    read(100, *) a, b
    integer, DIMENSION(a,b) :: c
    close (100)
end program matrix
```

I just keep getting the error code "Symbol 'a' already has basic type Integer.

The text file is just:

```
 3     3
 8     5     2
 1     9     3 
 3     4     1
```

In short, I'm just trying to short I'm just trying to sort the values in the rows, then order them in numerically.

Comment: You have changed the code, the array now has the name `c` instead of `A`, which caused the error message you state. You will now get a different error message, namely that you can't have a variable declaration after executable statements.

Comment: you cant have the declaration after the executable code. you need to declare `c` allocatable, then `allocate` after reading `a,b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

**Fortran is caseINsensitive:** `A` is the same as `a`

**Declarations have to precede execution statements**

The line

```
integer, DIMENSION(a,b) :: c
```

cannot be after the `open` or `read` statements.

What you can do is use allocatable arrays. Those get declared with a rank, but without a size, and can be allocated later to the size needed:

```
program matrix
    implicit none
    integer :: a, b
    integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: c
    open(unit=100, file='test.txt')
    read (100, *) a, b
    allocate(c(a,b))
    read(100, *) c
    close(100)
end program matrix
```

Comment: thanks a bunch, I see where I went wrong. I'm confused as to how I would be able to print out the results. I'm trying something along the lines of a double do loop and using write. Is this the right approach? I keep getting no implicit type

Comment: Depends, you can use the same shortcut that I've used for reading there. The single line `print '(3I4)', c` should print the whole array in three columns. As the matrix also consists of 3 columns, this matches up.